# How can I see the status of the latest CyanogenGen builds?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I see that CM10 nightlies for galaxysmtd have not been built for a while.  Is the status of the latest builds available anywhere, so that I can see *why* they haven't been built?

Comment: The buildbot's status used to be availabe [here](http://buildbot.teamdouche.net/) but it was removed for some reason I can't recall. Probably had to do something with annoying users demanding ETAs.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of CM - never ask for ETA's, changelogs!

Only recourse is to look up the [review](http://review.cyanogenmod.com) site instead and filter it out for the appropriate device instead to see what code changes were checked in/rejected, in this case, use this as a search query on the top right hand corner of the page.

```
status:open project:CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_galaxysmtd
```

Then can drill down the review, depending on what type of CyanogenMod ROM, be it GB, ICS or JB.

Usually, there is a reason as to why there's no build, check with their forum or IRC channel. :)

Comment: I've looked at the changelogs.  There are many accepted changes that haven't been released in a nightly yet.  I'm not asking for an ETA for a feature, nor am I asking *when* the next nightly will happen (note: I see that one was finally released a few hours ago), but rather I'm asking how I can see why the builds are being delayed.

Comment: @NathanFellman To be honest - this site is *not* Cyanogenmod, you need to direct this across over to their site and ask them.

Comment: Right, this is a Q&A site about Android stuff in general, including (among others) Cyanogenmod.  That's why there are currently 330 questions tagged "cyanogenmod".  If you don't have an answer, it's fair to leave the question unanswered.

Comment: Remember this much, we are not associated nor affiliated with CM developers. That's the point am making and its not fair to post CM specific questions indicating changelogs or why is there no build available. Other questions relating to CM is fine, its just dev stuff - we cannot answer :)

Comment: I didn't ask *why* the build wasn't available.  I asked *where* I can find the answer to that.  I'm well aware of the fact that CM is not affiliated with SE.  However, this is a general question related to usage of CM (in this case, how to update).  I wasn't expecting an answer such as, "the current build failed because there was no disk space."  That would be a prime candidate for closing as "too localized" and inappropriate for SE.  However, an answer with a pointer to the build logs would have been more than appropriate.

Comment: If you read the [FAQ], SE is about dealing with "real-life-problems concerning the user and his Android device", not about where/why the build logs is not available... just saying... the question is bordering on off-topic

Comment: @NathanFellman This is quite "borderline". If you check the [FAQ], you see we are devoted to deal with questions in the context *what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?* Your question does not indicate any problem, but rather -- forgive me the term -- looks like a "version junkie on a turkey" problem, which we cannot handle here. No offense meant -- forgive a non-native English speaker his rude words ;)